# Gene silencing in C. elegans

Tags: genetics, cell-biology, gene-expression

I am trying to silence the tph-1 (tryptophan hydroxylase) gene in C. elegans using the pLT63 plasmid to check if that particular gene has anything to do with the pharyneal pumping or not. Am I using the right plasmid for the purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"pLT63 contains 0.8 kb of the fem-1 gene inserted into the L4440 vector" ([1](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378111900005795)). The gene fem-1 is involved in determining the male sexual trait in *C. elegans* (you can verify this on uniprot). It may be best, however, to stick to a "normal" plasmid like L4440 that'll just have your tph-1 insert ligated in.

Comment: Is there any direct link between tph-1 and pharyngeal pumping in the worms that you know of?

Comment: I did read through some literature and while some evidence says tph-1(mg280), a deletion of an allele, alters the ability of the worms to fine-tune the speed of their feeding, i think that was [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1456143/). But overall, and we see in [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4137669/) study, the worms have relatively normal feeding. I haven't done the experimentation myself, however, so I can't 100% make a claim here.

Comment: Check out the WormBase site at www.wormbase.org. Just type tph-1 in the search box on the right hand side at the top of the page.